# How to merge two queries in Doctrine ORM

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have table "weights", where I have numbers of weights for various cameras.
I want to sum last numbers for this cameras, therefore I am using two queries.
First query selects max ids for every camera and second selects numbers of weight for these ids.

```
public function maxIds($cameras)
 {
     return $this->createQueryBuilder("c")
         ->select('MAX(c.id) ')
         ->where('c.camera IN (:value)')
         ->setParameter('value', $cameras)
         ->groupBy('c.camera')
         ->getQuery()
         ->getArrayResult();
 }

public function totalWeight($ids)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder("c")
        ->select('SUM(c.number)')
        ->where('c.id IN (:value)')
        ->setParameter('value', $ids)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

These two queries work fine, but I would like to combine them into one query.
I am trying with this:

```
public function testWeight($cameras)
{
    $qr = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('MAX(c.id) ')
        ->where('c.camera IN (:value)')
        ->setParameter('value', $cameras)
        ->groupBy('c.camera');

    $qr->andWhere($qr->expr()->in('c.id',
        $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
             ->select('SUM(c.number)')
             ->getDQL()
    ));

    return  $qr->getQuery()
               ->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

But I cannot success.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is untested however what you are trying to do is a sub query which you can achieve in Doctrine. I also made some minor improvements to your query:

```php
$subQuery = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$subQuery
    ->select('MAX(c2.id)')
    ->from(MyEntity::class, 'c2')
    ->where($subQuery->expr()->in('c2.camera', ':cameras'));
        
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
$queryBuilder
    ->select('SUM(c.number)')
    ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->in('c.id', $subQuery->getDQL()))
    ->setParameter('cameras', $cameras);
    ->getQuery()
    ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Comment: I tried it and I get Error: `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 77: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got 'FROM'`

Comment: My select was missing a closing bracket

Comment: Now there is another error: `Too few parameters: the query defines 1 parameters but you only bound 0`. It is for line `->getOneOrNullResult();`

Comment: I've amended my answer and moved the set parameter to the main query which should fix that

Comment: Now it is without errors, but return value of query is `Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder {#1229 ▼
  -_em: Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager {#793 …11}
  -_dqlParts: array:9 [▶]
  -_type: 0
  -_state: 1
  -_dql: "SELECT SUM(c.number) FROM App\Entity\Weight c WHERE c.id IN(SELECT MAX(c2.id) FROM App\Entity\Weight c2 WHERE c2.camera IN(:cameras))"
  -parameters: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#1230 ▶}
  -_firstResult: null
  -_maxResults: null
  -joinRootAliases: []
  #cacheable: false
  #cacheRegion: null
  #cacheMode: null
  #lifetime: 0
}`